# Error During Function. Where does all the data go?

Tags: r

I've developed a function where i use the return function to spit out a list of vectors.  Unfortunately there are still a few bugs in my code.  Once my function has failed due to error can i recover that list of vectors?

Comment: No, it is in the environment of that function which ends when the function does. You could assign to global env with `<<-` however, *caveat emptor*

Comment: are you looking for `options(error=recover)` ?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the lead.  It looks like i actually need to learn more about dump.frames

Comment: @KevinArseneau Great suggestion.  Once i get my functions into a package, this may actually be the best result for my team.

Answer (score 0):

Functions have their own scope, so if a function fails, the function will exit and no return value will be returned.  It's difficult to say what's making your function fail without looking at your code.  If the failure is due to something you have control of in your code, I suggest you solve it before relying on potentially function bogus results.  But if the failure is out of your control (e.g. calling an unavailable external data source) you can wrap your risky code in a [try](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/try.html) call to recover in the event of an error.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!  Great suggestions.  I am in the building phase of my functions so errors emerge all the time.  I've added a lot of tryCatch arguments, but sometimes even that cannot catch the errors.  I did find the source of the problem and fixed it, but i know i will come across more errors in the future.